# Putting char into a java string for each N characters

Tags: java, string, char

I have a java string, which has a variable length.

I need to put the piece `"<br>"` into the string, say each 10 characters.

For example this is my string:

```
`this is my string which I need to modify...I love stackoverlow:)`
```

How can I obtain this string?:

```
`this is my<br> string wh<br>ich I nee<br>d to modif<br>y...I love<br> stackover<br>flow:)`
```

Thanks

Comment: also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169699/string-manipulation-insert-a-character-every-4th-character

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Something like:

```
public static String insertPeriodically(
    String text, String insert, int period)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(
         text.length() + insert.length() * (text.length()/period)+1);

    int index = 0;
    String prefix = "";
    while (index < text.length())
    {
        // Don't put the insert in the very first iteration.
        // This is easier than appending it *after* each substring
        builder.append(prefix);
        prefix = insert;
        builder.append(text.substring(index, 
            Math.min(index + period, text.length())));
        index += period;
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: fantastic! and what about if I do not want to put <br> within words? for example avoiding things like: stackover<br>flow and putting directly <br> at the end of the word?

Comment: Then that's a significantly harder problem. A regular expression *may* be the best way there, but you'd need to state the requirements *very* precisely first.

Comment: a short version of your code with regex in this post.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530102/java-parse-string-and-add-line-break-every-100-characters

Comment: @Giancarlo if you do not want to break within the word, then you can probably just run a simple for loop and keep track of number of character after which you need to insert a `<br>` and insert it if only the current character is a `space`, or else move till the first space character and insert the `<br>`

Comment: @mtk: This question was asked over 6 years ago. I *suspect* the OP has moved on from this issue now :)

Comment: @JonSkeet Oh yes, i didn't realize.. :)

Answer (score 55):

Try:

```
String s = // long string
s.replaceAll("(.{10})", "$1<br>");
```

**EDIT:** The above works... most of the time.  I've been playing around with it and came across a problem: since it constructs a default Pattern internally it halts on newlines.  to get around this you have to write it differently.

```
public static String insert(String text, String insert, int period) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.{" + period + "})", Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
    return m.replaceAll("$1" + insert);
}
```

and the astute reader will pick up on another problem: you have to escape regex special characters (like "$1") in the replacement text or you'll get unpredictable results.

I also got curious and benchmarked this version against Jon's above.  This one is slower by an order of magnitude (1000 replacements on a 60k file took 4.5 seconds with this, 400ms with his).  Of the 4.5 seconds, only about 0.7 seconds was actually constructing the Pattern.  Most of it was on the matching/replacement so it doesn't even ledn itself to that kind of optimization.

I normally prefer the less wordy solutions to things.  After all, more code = more potential bugs.  But in this case I must concede that Jon's version--which is really the naive implementation (I mean that in a **good way**)--is significantly better.

Comment: I'm getting:
Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ )
for "(.{1,10}\s+"

Comment: Fixed it.  It should've been \\s but I'd mistakenly assumed you wanted to break on word boundaries.  You don't so the above should work and is much easier.

Answer (score 22):

I got here from [String Manipulation insert a character every 4th character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169699/string-manipulation-insert-a-character-every-4th-character) and was looking for a solution on Android with Kotlin.

Just adding a way to do that with Kotlin (you got to love the simplicity of it)

```
val original = "123498761234"
val dashed = original.chunked(4).joinToString("-") // 1234-9876-1234
```

Answer (score 15):

You can use the regular expression '..' to match each two characters and replace it with "$0 " to add the space:

s = s.replaceAll("..", "$0 ");
You may also want to trim the result to remove the extra space at the end.

Alternatively you can add a negative lookahead assertion to avoid adding the space at the end of the string:

s = s.replaceAll("..(?!$)", "$0 ");

For example:

`String s = "23423412342134";
s = s.replaceAll("....", "$0<br>");
System.out.println(s);`

Output: `2342<br>3412<br>3421<br>34`

Comment: Excelent answer

Comment: Learn to give recognition. This is taken from @Mark Byers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149342/adding-space-between-characters

Answer (score 3):

To avoid chopping off the words...

Try:

```
    int wrapLength = 10;
    String wrapString = new String();

    String remainString = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

    while(remainString.length()>wrapLength){
        int lastIndex = remainString.lastIndexOf(" ", wrapLength);
        wrapString = wrapString.concat(remainString.substring(0, lastIndex));
        wrapString = wrapString.concat("\n");

        remainString = remainString.substring(lastIndex+1, remainString.length());
    }

    System.out.println(wrapString);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind a dependency on a [third-party library](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/16.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html) and don't mind [regexes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12295805/59087):

```
import com.google.common.base.Joiner;

/**
 * Splits a string into N pieces separated by a delimiter.
 *
 * @param text The text to split.
 * @param delim The string to inject every N pieces.
 * @param period The number of pieces (N) to split the text.
 * @return The string split into pieces delimited by delim.
 */
public static String split( final String text, final String delim, final int period ) {
    final String[] split = text.split("(?<=\\G.{"+period+"})");
    return Joiner.on(delim).join(split);
}
```

Then:

```
split( "This is my string", "<br/>", 5 );
```

This doesn't split words at spaces but the question, as stated, doesn't ask for word-wrap.

Comment: In Java 8 you can use `return String.join(delim, split);` instead of guava.

Answer (score 1):

```
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i += 10) {
    buf.append(myString.substring(i, i + 10);
    buf.append("\n");
}
```

You can get more efficient than that, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Missing a trailing paren on the first append, also goes out of the string bounds

Comment: You should probably use StringBuilder not StringBuffer.

Comment: For big Strings it might be a good idea to set the initial size of the StringBuffer/StringBuilder to (myString.length()*1.1) this way resizing the internal buffer will be avoided.

Comment: This solution is missing an end parenthesis and throws an OutOfBoundException if myString.length() is not perfectly divisible by 10. I see someone else already mentioned this.
However, no one mentioned that this can be more efficient by evaluating myString.length() before the loop, not every single loop.

Answer (score 1):

I've unit tested this solution for boundary conditions:

```
public String padded(String original, int interval, String separator) {
    String formatted = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < original.length(); i++) {
        if (i % interval == 0 && i > 0) {
            formatted += separator;
        }
        formatted += original.substring(i, i+1);
    }

    return formatted;
}
```

Call with:

```
padded("this is my string which I need to modify...I love stackoverflow:)", 10, "<br>");
```

Answer (score 0):

How about 1 method to split the string every N characters:

```
public static String[] split(String source, int n)
{
    List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

    int start = 0;
    int end = 10;

    while(end < source.length)
    {
        results.add(source.substring(start, end);
        start = end;
        end += 10;
    }

    return results.toArray(new String[results.size()]);
}
```

Then another method to insert something after each piece:

```
public static String insertAfterN(String source, int n, String toInsert)
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    for(String piece : split(source, n))
    {
        result.append(piece);
        if(piece.length == n)
            result.append(toInsert);
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following method takes three parameters. The first is the text that you want to modify. The second parameter is the text you want to insert every n characters. The third is the interval in which you want to insert the text at.

```
private String insertEveryNCharacters(String originalText, String textToInsert, int breakInterval) {
    String withBreaks = "";
    int textLength = originalText.length(); //initialize this here or in the start of the for in order to evaluate this once, not every loop
    for (int i = breakInterval , current = 0; i <= textLength || current < textLength; current = i, i += breakInterval ) {
        if(current != 0) {  //do not insert the text on the first loop
            withBreaks += textToInsert;
        }
        if(i <= textLength) { //double check that text is at least long enough to go to index i without out of bounds exception
            withBreaks += originalText.substring(current, i);
        } else { //text left is not longer than the break interval, so go simply from current to end.
            withBreaks += originalText.substring(current); //current to end (if text is not perfectly divisible by interval, it will still get included)
        }
    }
    return withBreaks;
}
```

You would call to this method like this:

```
String splitText = insertEveryNCharacters("this is my string which I need to modify...I love stackoverlow:)", "<br>", 10);
```

The result is:

```
this is my<br> string wh<br>ich I need<br> to modify<br>...I love <br>stackoverl<br>ow:)
```

^This is different than your example result because you had a set with 9 characters instead of 10 due to human error ;)

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin Regex version:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {    
    var original = "this is my string which I need to modify...I love stackoverlow:)"
    println(original)
    val regex = Regex("(.{10})")
    original = regex.replace(original, "$1<br>")
    println(original)
}
```

[Kotlin Playground](https://pl.kotl.in/GFTm5kNWk)

Answer (score 0):

```java
String s = // long string
String newString = String.join("<br>", s.split("(?<=\\G.{10})"));
```

No final `<br>` is added if `s` length is multiple of `10`.

Thanks to [@cletus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18393/cletus) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54346446/12711179) for the inspiration

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin you can used the chunked method to do most of the work and join with a separator at the end. Here I am adding a dash after every 4th character.

```
longString.chunked(4).joinToString("-")
```