# String Manipulation insert a character every 4th character

Tags: java, android, string, concatenation, android-edittext

In Android if I have an edit text and the user entered 123456789012, how could I get the program to insert a dash every 4th character. **ie: 1234-5678-9012**?

I guess you need to say something along the lines of:- 
`a=Characters 1~4, b=Characters 5~8, c=Characters 9-12`, Result **= a + "-" + b + "-" + c**. But I am unsure of how that would look in Android.

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
String s = "123456789012";
String s1 = s.substring(0, 4);
String s2 = s.substring(4, 8);
String s3 = s.substring(8, 12);

String dashedString = s1 + "-" + s2 + "-" + s3;
//String.format is extremely slow. Just concatenate them, as above.
```

[`substring()` Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29)

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you for that very clear answer. Much appreciated.

Comment: Eclipse underlines substring & I get the following error when I try this
The method substring(EditText, int, int) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}
What should I do?

Comment: Just to revive an old answer, this answer is wrong. String.substring() take indexes inclusive, exclusive. Therefore, the arguments should be (0, 4) (4, 8) (8, 12).

Answer (score 6):

Or another alternative way using a StringBuilder rather than to split the string in multiple parts and then join them :

```
String original = "123456789012";
int interval = 4;
char separator = '-';

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(original);

for(int i = 0; i < original.length() / interval; i++) {
    sb.insert(((i + 1) * interval) + i, separator);
}

String withDashes = sb.toString();
```

Comment: It has a problem of ending with the separator. I mean, if there is no more character after the separator, it should not add a separator.

Comment: @DamnVegetables (original.length() / interval)-1 , subtract one for the loop size

Answer (score 1):

Alternative way:

```
String original = "123456789012";
int dashInterval = 4;
String withDashes = original.substring(0, dashInterval);
for (int i = dashInterval; i < original.length(); i += dashInterval) {
    withDashes += "-" + original.substring(i, i + dashInterval);
}

return withDashes;
```

If you needed to pass strings with lengths that were not multiples of the dashInterval you'd have to write an extra bit to handle that to prevent index out of bounds nonsense.