# android: limit of 10 characters per line TextView

Tags: android, textview

I read value from EditText and write it to TextView

```
editTitle1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
              public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
              }

              public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
              }

              public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                  s = editTitle1.getText().toString();
                  textTitle1.setText(s);

              }
           });
```

And I want that in one line - maximum 10 characters, so if all 20 characters - it's two line in TextView with 10 chars per line. How I can do this?
I try android:maxLength="10" but it does not help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define a method that returns a string formatted to have 10 characters per line:

```
public String getTenCharPerLineString(String text){

    String tenCharPerLineString = "";
    while (text.length() > 10) {

        String buffer = text.substring(0, 10);
        tenCharPerLineString = tenCharPerLineString + buffer + "/n";
        text = text.substring(10);
    }

    tenCharPerLineString = tenCharPerLineString + text.substring(0);
    return tenCharPerLineString;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I edited the answer given by ramaral he used wrong escape sequence

```
public String getTenCharPerLineString(String text){

    String tenCharPerLineString = "";
    while (text.length() > 10) {

        String buffer = text.substring(0, 10);
        tenCharPerLineString = tenCharPerLineString + buffer + "\n";
        text = text.substring(10);
    }

    tenCharPerLineString = tenCharPerLineString + text.substring(0);
    return tenCharPerLineString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following 2 attributes to the TextView definition:

```
android:singleLine="false"  
android:maxems="10"
```

Comment: The result is the same:(

Comment: Try setting the `android:maxWidth="size"` instead of max ems, and replace the "size" with the size you prefer. For example, 100dip.

Comment: you can also just write a simple function to add a newline character after every 10 characters [like here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/537190/2333395)