# Dynamically increase the size of textview

Tags: android, textview

I have edittext where user will enter the message.So I want to display the message in Textview.Now I want in a textview in one line only 23 character should be displayed and the remaining text should be displayed in the next line in textview.How can this be achieved in Android.

Comment: Your TextView should support multines and when writting text into it use \n for a new line.

Comment: set the android:maxLines = 2 and adjust the size of your textview

Comment: you can use \n after completing your 23 characters in textview , so it will automatically start from the new line.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21364923/android-limit-of-10-characters-per-line-textview

Comment: refer https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
String your_data="abcdef......";
String value=setText(your_data);
textView.setText(value);
```

setText method:

```
public String setText(String text){

    String lineString = "";
    while (text.length() > 23) {

        String buffer = text.substring(0, 23);
        lineString = lineString + buffer + "/n";
        text = text.substring(23);
    }

    lineString = lineString + text.substring(0);
    return lineString;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@user7144720

get `EditText` text inside one `String` variable

```
String finalString = "";
String textToShow = sampleEditText.getText().toString();
if (textToShow.length > 23) {
    finalString = textToShow.substring(0,23) + "\n" + textToShow.substring(23);
}
else {
    finalString = textToShow;
}
//then set finalString for your textview

textViewDisplay.setText(finalString);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
android:maxLines="2"
```