# Add a character after every 10 characters in a string using subString() function

Tags: java, string, substring

Suppose the `string` is like this:

```
String msg = "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"
```

I want to **add** a `character` supposing 'f' after every 10 character iteration using `subString` function because I can't call `StringBuilder` class ( used it for `insert` or `append` functionality).

Comment: No it's not duplicate, please do read the problem!!!

Comment: Well, this is some form of homework. In that case, you need to use material you learned in class. Homework questions are supposed to show your own attempt to solve the problem, and explain where you have a problem in it.

Comment: why can't you use a StringBuilder, it is what it will be used anyway when your code will be compiled

Comment: Nicolas, I'm basically writing my program in a bean file for groovy thats why I cant put StringBuilder function.

Comment: @RonaldoKillergod It is a duplicate of your previous question.

Comment: Your previous question is also a duplicate of some other question. Sounds like a linkedlist of posts.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){
     int i = 10;

    String msg = "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"; 
       while(i <= msg.length())
        {
           msg = msg.substring(0, i) + "f" + msg.substring(i, msg.length());
           i = i + 11; 

        }
    System.out.println(msg);
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It may help you

```
public static String insertPeriodically(String text, String insert, int period)
{
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(text.length() + insert.length() * (text.length()/period)+1);

int index = 0;
String prefix = "";
while (index < text.length())
{
    // Don't put the insert in the very first iteration.
    // This is easier than appending it *after* each substring
    builder.append(prefix);
    prefix = insert;
    builder.append(text.substring(index, 
        Math.min(index + period, text.length())));
    index += period;
}
return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: This answer is exact copy of @JonSkeet answer in the [Putting char into a java string for each N characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/537174/putting-char-into-a-java-string-for-each-n-characters).