# JasperReports: How to break lines base on a character count

Tags: java, jasper-reports, line-breaks

I have a long string (150 characters). I put text_1 string parameter in the report and I want automatic jasper breakline at the 50th character.

```
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TEXT_1}]]></textFieldExpression>
```

Example:

My string: `012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789`

I want to print with JasperReports:

```
01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
```

I want to execute in Jasper, not excute in Java
Please suggest me a solution.

Comment: I personally like [solution by Dave Jarvis](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37977587/876298). In this case you should add import to your template to use this class/method. You can use `"\n"` character or `<br>` tag

Answer (score 7):

### Approaches

There are a few approaches:

- Set the width of *textField* and set **isStretchWithOverflow** attribute as **true**. This solution depends on the font metrics.
- Use a *Java* expression. For example you can use *Guava* library. In this case you should add ***import*** statement to the template.

### Example

In this example, only the **Title** band is used to demonstrate both solutions. An empty datasource is used.

#### Report Template

Demonstrates both variants of solving the task.

The width of the first *textField* is enough only for showing 50 symbols. With help **isStretchWithOverflow** property the text will be split into several rows (the height of *textField* will increase dynamically).

The second *textField*'s expression (look at **textFieldExpression**) uses the *Guava* library.

`Joiner.on("\n").join(Splitter.fixedLength(50).split(value))` - The *[Splitter.fixedLength(int)](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html#fixedLength(int))* method allow us to split string by every *50* characters and the *[Joiner.on(String)](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html#on(java.lang.String))* method help us to join strings with newline character.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="break_lines" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <import value="com.google.common.base.*"/>
    <parameter name="LONG_TEXT" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <title>
        <band height="347" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement x="110" y="10" width="280" height="30"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{LONG_TEXT}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement x="20" y="100" width="525" height="30"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[Joiner.on("\n").join(Splitter.fixedLength(50).split($P{LONG_TEXT}))]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

#### Output result

The output result in *Jaspersoft Studio* will be:

[image: The result in JSS]

A *150*-character string is split into *3* rows, each row contains *50* characters.