# Stream equivalent for appending dash(-) after every 3rd char of string

Tags: java, java-stream

I have created simple for loop based solution to append dash(-) on every third digit.

```java
 private String appendedDashOnEachThirdDigit(String digitString) {
    char digits[] = digitString.toCharArray();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
      char ch = digits[i];
      builder.append(ch);
      if ((i + 1) % 3 == 0 && i - 1 != digits.length) {
        builder.append('-');
      }
    }
    return builder.toString();
  }
```

Now I want to create equivalent java 8 stream based solution. This is very basic case and I want to know how this can be done with stream api?

I have created this basic stream function:-

```html
  private String appendedDashOnEachThirdDigitByStream(String digitString) {
    //char[] chars = digitString.toCharArray();
    //return IntStream.range(0, chars.length)
    //    .filter(i -> (i + 1) % 3 == 0 && i - 1 != chars.length)
    //    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(),
    //        new Function<List<Object>, Object>() {
    //        }))
   return digitString.chars()
        .mapToObj(value -> String.valueOf((char) value))
        .collect(Collectors.joining("-"));
  }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far using streams?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537174/putting-char-into-a-java-string-for-each-n-characters

Comment: That's not even a particularly good way to do it without streams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is possible it is not best solution.

```
    class T {
        final int i;
        final int c;

        public T(int i, int c) {

            this.i = i;
            this.c = c;
        }
    }
    int[] i = {0};


    String res = "123456789".chars()
            .mapToObj(c -> new T(i[0]++, c))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x.i / 3))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getKey))
            .map(x ->
                    x.getValue().stream().mapToInt(y -> y.c)
                            .mapToObj(y -> String.valueOf((char)y))
                            .collect(Collectors.joining())

            ).collect(Collectors.joining("-"));


    System.out.println("res = " + res);
```

Main problem here is that stream is good when your elements is independent. In your scenario processing depend on position so it required wired grouping.

Comment: This works but definitely it is hard for me to read compared to for loop version. Its hard to interpret!  But thanks for your help I have accepted your answer! :)