# How to concatenate Special symbol as colon after every 2 character in Android

Tags: java, android, string, kotlin, stringbuilder

I want to concatenate or append special character as colon **:** after an every 2 character in String.

For Example: 
Original String are as follow:

```
String abc =AABBCCDDEEFF;
```

After concatenate or append colon are as follow:

```
  String abc =AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF;
```

So my question is how we can achieve this in android.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below code, if you want to do without Math class functions.

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int a =0; a < abc.length(); a++) {
        stringBuilder.append(abc.charAt(a));
        if (a % 2 == 1 && a < abc.length() -1)
            stringBuilder.append(":");
    }
```

Here

1. **a % 2 == 1 ** ==> this conditional statement is used to append **":"**
2. **a < abc.length() -1** ==> this conditional statement is used not to add **":"**

in last entry. Hope this makes sense. If you found any problem please let me know.

Answer (score 6):

In Kotlin use `chunked(2)` to split the `String` every 2 chars and rejoin with `joinToString(":")`:

```
val str = "AABBCCDDEEFF"
val newstr = str.chunked(2).joinToString(":")
println(newstr)
```

will print

```
AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(abc.length() * 3 / 2);
String delim = "";
for (int i = 0; i < abc.length(); i += 2) {
  sb.append(delim);
  sb.append(abc, i, Math.min(i + 2, abc.length()));
  delim = ":";
}
String newAbc = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the Kotlin way. without `StringBuilder`**

```
val newString: String = abc.toCharArray().mapIndexed { index, c ->
            if (index % 2 == 1 && index < abc.length - 1) {
                "$c:"
            } else {
                c
            }
        }.joinToString("")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `String.split` and `String.join` (`TextUtils.join(":", someList)` for android) to first split the string at each second char and join it using the delimiter you want. Example:

```
String abc = "AABBCCDDEEFF";
String def = String.join(":", abc.split("(?<=\\G.{2})"));
System.out.println(def);
//AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF
```